# Как проверить, загрузилась ли страница?

Tags: javascript

Можно ли с помощью условия if проверить наступило ли событие window.onload  ?

Не нужно предлогать варианты типа

```
window.onload = function (){ ..... }
```

Это не подходит, нужно именно условие, если страница загрузилась то выполняется одна функция, если страница не загрузилась то выполнется другая функция, ну и желательно получить ответ на чистом js, без всяких фреймворков типа jquery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var PageLoaded = false;

window.onload = function() {
   PageLoaded = true;
}
```

или

```
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
```

Answer (score 2):

Следите за свойством document.readyState (может принимать значения loading, interactive, complete)

Answer (score 2):

Чувак. Страница грузиться в асинхронном режиме. Т.о. до тех пор, пока не сработает событие window.onload, страница считается не загруженной (да и скрипты на этой странице тоже). После - считается, что она загружена.

И кстати, это еще не значит, что в момент срабатывания window.onload будет построен весь дом, загружены все скрипты и ты сможешь взаимодействовать с нодами.

Если ты опишешь более развернуто тот функционал, который хочешь реализовать, можно будет дать тебе более конкретные рекомендации.

В любом случае забудь о том, как реализуются алгоритмы проверки в яп, где исполнение кода идет последовательно. В JS этого нет. В JS нужно использовать событийную модель и деферреды, чтобы надежно контролировать состояние выполнения различных операций.